# Finding the Correct Junit Version to use in pom .XML file

Tags: java, maven, automation, frameworks, appium

I am creating an appium framework and I'm wondering what is a stable version of Junit I can use?  The default version found in my maven project (Junit 3.8.1) is VERY VERY OLD but when I try to use an up to date version of JUnit in eclipse, it doesn't like it and puts a red 'x' in my project.

So what can I use with

```
 Java. 1.8
 Appium desktop  1.8.1
 java-client 5.0.4
 selenium-java 3.11.0
 TestNG 6.11
```

Would it be easier to not use JUnit at all?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.4</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: You don't need to use junit if you are using testng for appium.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitively consider switching to Junit 4.12.

Try downloading the latest version of Eclipse (or switch to IntelliJ , it's awesome).

Use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Else you could try a junit alternative like TestNG.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried updating my Appium project's JUnit recently and I could not get any version past 4.12 to work at all.  I tried every single newer version listed on the Maven repository, and just decided to stay at 4.12

Comment: 4.12 is good. It has plenty of annotations and works well with "newish" technologies like spring-boot

Comment: Thanks Guys you are all a bunch of legends.  I thinkI'm going to use TestNG for the appium framework